# MeteorJS Iron Router installation crashing app

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I have problem with my application, I'm learning with "Discover Meteor" book, but frankly I have an error that I don't know how to fix.

I'm right now at "Routing" chapter, and when I install iron-router package with

```
mrt add iron-router
```

my whole app just crushes and I don't know how to fix it.

Here are the errors:

```
TypeError: Template.__create__ is not a function
TypeError: Parent is undefined
TypeError: Iron.Layout is not a constructor
TypeError: Package['iron-router'] is undefined
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
ReferenceError: Template is not defined
ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mrt add iron-router` was deprecated

try with

`meteor add iron:router` instead

Answer (score 0):

For template undefined error,

try run `meteor reset` command and then start server with `meteor`

Note: `meteor reset` will do reset your build and also local mongodb data

Update: It should remove the error but anyways try full uninstall of `meteor` from your system and install it again.

The meteor core installation might get corrupted while auto updating from 0.8 to 1.0 version

Uninstall meteor -

```
rm -rf ~/.meteor

rm -rf /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

Install

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Above will install latest version of meteor i.e 1.0

and after that now update your project with

```
cd <your-project-directory>

meteor update --release 1.0.0
```